# Openmp segfault when passing private variable but not when variable is declared within parallel region

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

The title says it all. When I declare array x outside the parallel region and pass it as a private variable to the threads, I get a segfault.
When I declare the variable within the parallel region, everything works fine.
I am interested in passing the variable as private rather than declaring it, hence I need help to debug the issue. 
Here is how it looks like:

```
//Case1 - doesn't work (segfault)
x = (double *) malloc (solution * sizeof(double));
#pragma omp parallel for private(x)
for...

//Case2 - works
#pragma omp parallel for 
for...
    x = (double *) malloc (solution * sizeof(double));
```

I am using 72 threads and I've set the KMP_STACKSIZE to 1m as well as

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

UPDATE

I still get the segfault despite John's suggestion. Here is the actual piece of code. I am actually using CPLEX optimisation library. I've also tried with memcpy for the private variable allocation.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(lp,env)
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    CPXENVptr envi =env;
    CPXLPptr    lpi = lp
    CPXLpopt(envi,lpi);//this is where the segfault happens
}
```

Worth noting the CPLXLpopt command changes the size of both envi and lpi variables/
Do you recommend any debugger for openmp?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you actually intend to do, please provide an [mcve].

Comment: In the first case you are making your pointer variable private. That means, each thread receives its private **uninitialised** copy of the pointer itself. This does not create private copies of what is being pointed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertions about one code working and the other not are approximate at best.  In fact, *neither* code even compiles successfully as presented.  It seems virtually certain that the misbehavior reported in one case depends also on how variable `x` is used in the parallel section.

With that said, if the only difference between the working and non-working code is the placement of the declaration of and assignment to `x`, as shown, then it is unsurprising that the version that assigns `x` outside the parallel region segfaults.  The OpenMP specs describe the private `x`s in scope in each thread running in the parallel region of your Case 1 this way:

> A new list item of the same type, with automatic storage duration, is allocated for the construct. [...] ***The new list item is initialized, or has an undefined initial value, as if it had been locally declared without an initializer.***

(from OpenMP 4.5, 2.15.3.3; emphasis added)

That is, the local `x`s inside your parallel loop do not start with the value that the (separate) `x` outside the loop has.  Their initial values are indeterminate (per C for an automatic object declared without an initializer).  Using that initial value produces undefined behavior, which might very well manifest as a segmentation fault.

You could fix this by allowing `x` to be shared, and using a different private variable in the parallel section, initialized from the shared `x`.  Something like this, for example:

```
x = (double *) malloc (solution * sizeof(double));
#pragma omp parallel for
for (double *y = x; ...
```

(`x` is shared and `y` is private by default).  That serves the scenario where you want each thread to have a private *pointer* to the same shared space.

Note, however, that the memory to which `x` points is shared no matter what.  If you want each thread to have its own, separate, dynamically-allocated space, then each one needs to allocate such space itself (and subsequently to free that space).  Even in that case that allocated space is technically shared, but if the threads do not publish any pointers to their allocated spaces then other threads will be unable to access them.